# Consider the set of integers $\mathbb{ℤ}$ with the digital line topology. Find a proper subset of the integers that is dense in $\mathbb{ℤ}$

Tags: general-topology

The digital line topology: For each odd integer we have a basis element $B(n)=\{n\}$. We regard each even integer $n$ as representing the boundary between $n − 1$ and $n + 1$. Associated to each even $n$ we have a basis element $b(n)=\{n-1,n,n+1\}$. Thus, in the digital line, every odd integer is an open set, and every even integer is a closed set.

A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is called dense if Cl(A) = X, and $y\in Cl(A)$ if and only if every open set containing $y$ intersects $A$.

I propose that the the subset of odd integers is dense in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Any non-empty open set contains a $B(n)$ or a $b(n)$, hence in the first case the odd number $n$ and in the second case the odd number $n+1$.